# multidimensional array of vectors pointing to class objects c++

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

I'm not exactly sure what's happening as I am relatively new to c++

I have globally defined the following above my main loop

```
vector<Character*> monsters[2][3][6];
vector<Item*> loot[2][3][6];
vector<NPC*> npc[2][3][6];
vector<Objects*> objects[2][3][6];
```

Inside my Character.h file I have also defined the objects array

```
extern vector<Objects*> objects[2][3][6];
```

Everything was working fine until I created the objects array.
It appears that if I add more than 8 objects to the monsters array strange values start appearing into objects and the size of objects increases.
My code is a mess and I'm not sure exactly what I should include here. I hope this is enough to give you an idea of what I'm on about.

I haven't tested this thoroughly so it may very well happen to all of my arrays...

Comment: Why would you do that instead of a nested vector or a nested `std::array` of `vector`?

Comment: Can you show the code you use to insert an object/monster into the arrays? And how you access the array to see it contains strange objects?

Comment: @pmr I wasn't sure what approach to take as I am fairly new. the reason I chose this is because I have it set up monster[map][zoneX][zoneY] then a vector of all the monsters in that map zone.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am guessing you were going to check is I was inserting them incorrectly? it turns out I didn't make the array big enough.

Comment: You should try and fabricate an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the monsters array was not large enough so it was "overflowing" and placing objects outside of the array, thus ending up within another array.

Apologies for inconvenience. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you want to write your own small `Grid` class that fits your need or use [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html) to handle such cases. Working with nested raw arrays leads to a mess in the long run. Maybe you also want to avoid storing pointers and store objects by value.